# How to modify an SD card so it will be read only?

Tags: sd, write-protect

I checked SD card pins and their descriptions and saw that there is a "data input" and a "data out". If I covered, removed the data in pin, would it block all the writing requests to the card?

Comment: How will the card know what address to read from then? Not all input signals are data to be written.

Comment: SD cards have write protect switches don't they?

Comment: https://www.flexxon.com/write-once-read-many-worm-sd-microsd-cards/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It would just render the card completely unusable. (OK, that's kind of a write protection too – but so would be smashing it with a rock.)

The SD card and the host talk a protocol, in which the host asks the card things like "could you please turn on", "go into this and that speed mode" and "give me this and that data".

The data in and out pins refer to the direction of the communication of host to card; without the data in path, the card couldn't be asked for data.

SD cards themselves don't offer a proper standardized built-in write protection. There's a small "notch" that some cards have that a reader can check. If it's there, it could *consider* the card write-protected. That's the same "write-protection" mechanism as in old music cassettes: totally up to the reader to support and fully up to the host operating system to respect (or not).

**Some** cards come with semi-/nonstandard commands that can disable writing in the card firmware – but that's just relying on software in the card instead of the host to do the write protection, and again, it's not standardized, so if supported, it's something only possible with a specific program.

Comment: I found a tool to do that so. It says it can make it write protected permanently. But can it be reversed physically is what i wonder. https://github.com/BertoldVdb/sdtool

Comment: @heathcliff I mistyped; please read my updated answer. Essentially, you can't properly write-protect an SD card, unless its firmware really wants to do that in a vendor-proprietary way (and that's only as secure as you trust that firmware, i.e. not at all)